# deploy iphone app on ipod

Tags: iphone, xcode, deployment, ipod

i implemented an application for iPhone, i just wanted to know that can i deploy iPhone app on iPod device via Xcode?

is it good idea or not?

my application needs internet connection every time, because to perform any operation app have to make request to web-server and web-server will response.

thank you in advance

Comment: When you say iPod, do you mean iPod Touch?

Comment: @Black Frog it's inherit as there is not public development for any other iPod :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To install an app to an iOS device, (iPod Touch, iPhone, iPad) you will need to purchase a developer certificate from Apple.  You will need to be a member, visit [iOS Dev Center](http://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/index.action) to join.  The membership cost $99 for a year and you can deploy/test your app on 100 devices.  After your testing, you can submit your app to "App Store."

Comment: that means i can deploy my app on iPod from xcode by generating  certificate and also on iPhone device, i mean I just have to pay 1 time for any device.

Comment: When you become a paid developer, you will be able to create provisioning profiles for any iOS devices up to 100 device. So your friends can test your application.

Answer (score 1):

It makes no difference if you use an iPhone or an iPod, so long as your app doesn't use any features that only the iPhone has (vibrate, making calls, etc). They run the same OS, and so any app that you can install on an iPhone you can also install on an iPod.

*Edit* I'm assuming you mean iPod Touch...